# Filtering by rows "grouped" by DISTINCT ON clause

Tags: postgresql

I came across the `DISTINCT ON` clause which I can use to join with the last row on the other table. For example, the following query will show the last access of all users:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (user.id)
    user.id, access.login_time, access.geocoded_location

FROM user

JOIN access
    on access.user_id = user.id

ORDER BY user.id ASC, access.id DESC
```

Now I would like to get the users whose last access was before 2014.

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (user.id)
    user.id, access.login_time, access.geocoded_location

FROM user

JOIN access
    on access.user_id = user.id

WHERE
    access.login_time < '2014-01-01 00:00:00+00'

ORDER BY user.id ASC, access.id DESC
```

Is this query going to retrieve the users I expect, or is it going to get the *last access before 2014 jan first of all users*?

In more general terms, `postgres` will first filter the rows then remove the duplicates, or first remove the duplicates then filter the rows?

If it is filtering before removing the duplicates, what other solutions do you suggest?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The condition in the `where` clause is applied just after the derived table in the `from` clause is built and before the `select` list. So you will need to apply the condition to the result of the whole query

```
select *
from (
    select distinct on (user.id)
        user.id, access.login_time, access.geocoded_location
    from
        user
        inner join
        access on access.user_id = user.id
    order by user.id asc, access.id desc
) s
where login_time < '2014-01-01 00:00:00+00'
```

Comment: You are right, I just got a test that matched your answer.

Comment: Is the `login_time < '2014-01-01 00:00:00+00'` condition in the outer query use the index on `access.login_time`?

Comment: @Eric No, it will not use it.

Comment: Does that mean that when filtering `VIEWS` the indexes aren't used at all?